# log4net method GetLogger() Equivalent in Serilog

Tags: c#, log4net, serilog

### Brief Backround

We are replacing in our project the `log4net` to `Serilog`. In many of our classes we are using the method `LogManager.GetLogger` of log4net when giving as a parameter the class name using `MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType`, so we could know in which class the log was written.

### My Question Is

Is there any method which is equivalent in Serilog which can give me the logger? I know that there is the option of `ForContext()` which you can specify the class you're in, but I still don't know how to get an instance of a logger without some kind of logManager.
**P.S**
To give a logger as a parameter to each class constructor (instead of using `Getlogger()`) would take some time and I would really prefer to avoid this option.

Comment: I've run into this exact problem, what did you end up doing?

Comment: @Q-bertsuit: same boat. Taking a look at serilog's [implementation of Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-extensions-logging/blob/dev/src/Serilog.Extensions.Logging/Extensions/Logging/SerilogLoggerProvider.cs) - where Microsoft specifies that implementations must implement `CreateLogger(string name)` - I was curious how they did it themselves. Turns out, they basically reuse the same `Serilog.Log.Logger` instance for all loggers and keep wrapping it with calls to `ForContext()`. At least, as far as I can tell.

Comment: @Q-bertsuit, sorry for the delay answer. Actually as you can see I was facing this problem about 2 and half years ago. As far as I remember, and as mentioned in other comments, I used the `ForContext()` and edited the type for the Elasticsearch sink.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After I did some research, I founded out that there is **NO** `Log4Net` GetLogger() equivalent in Serilog.

Comment: This conclusion is wrong. There's no need to create a new logger instance to configure it - configuration isn't performed at the logger level to begin with. `FromContext` will include context information. The *actual* configuration already uses categories and other context information

Comment: I agree with you, and thank you for adding this information, I think I originally thought it would maybe save some time for people to look for such function - it was a while ago so I cant *really* remember, maybe I could write it in a different more elaborate way. But, as for the original question, still there is no equivalent. I think that the question "is there is a different, better way to face multiple configurations" is a bit different.

Comment: Got me it seems like FromContext actually does the exact same thing LogManager.GetLogger? Am I missing soemthing?

Answer (score 1):

Answer is **NO**, but maybe [**Source Contexts**](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Writing-Log-Events#source-contexts) is  what you needed.

There is an example from Serilog's Wiki:

```cs
var myLog = Log.ForContext<MyClass>();
myLog.Information("Hello!");
```

Answer (score 0):

What about the SourceContext Property wich is set in a context?
https://github.com/serilog/serilog/issues/91

Comment: It seems that it is working like ForContext. I need to get a logger instance which I can edit it config

Comment: Are you on dotnet core?

Comment: Then Log.Logger could be your friend :)

Comment: I don't understand how Log.logger is helping me. I am using it when I initializing my Serilog.  Can you please explain what you mean?